# matlab - concatenate image pixel value into one row or one column of data

Tags: matlab

i am doing an image recognition project and would like to use the pixel values as the medium to differentiate 2 different images via matlab nprtool. To prepare the training and testing data set, the data has to be in either a column or a row form. So how can I concatenate pixel values of an image (for example 100x100) into 1 column or 1 row of data? What is the most appropriate way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if your matrix is called `image`, use the `:` operator

```
  image(:)
```

Answer (score 2):

Into one row :

```
 image = reshape( image, 1, []);
```

Into one column:

```
 image = reshape( image, [], 1);
```

---

Here is another way:

Into one row :

```
 image = image(:)';
```

Into one column:

```
 image = image(:);
```